# How can I push past the Maze consistently

Tags: inflation-rpg

I've picked up this game, and played around a bit. My current equipment is as follows:
Hard Sword: 3000/290%; Samurai Armour: 1400/240%; HP Gem+2; Attack Gem+2; Agi Gem+2; Recover Necklace; Exp Gem=1x2. My base ability level is 5 and my character of choice, top-left atk/agi, is level 2.

My current strategy is Fox-Sphinx-Dragon-Eye-Thunder-Earth-Fire-Water-Hydra-Disk; with stops as necessary for XP to continue pushing, and for any ? ? ? bonus I come across.

I can fairly consistently reach the Maze with ~10-15 battles remaining, and have discovered a second disk once, which brought me to a next map which i was unable to explore much due to the rapidly ramping levels. What changes can I make to progress further in the game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get exp gems +3 and or +4.  from eye boss and hydra boss(behind purple mother) respectivly. Mabey elemental weapons+1 or whatever you can get your hands on that scales well late. Definetly buy better HP gem and Attack gem. you can ignore agility gem and use high lvl exp gems as much as you can. Again try and use as menny and high exp gems as you can for as long as you can as they will help you over level for later difficulties! Then it's just a grind for better weapons/armors /gems  but this will get you started!

The wikia is a great resource for information: http://inflation-rpg.wikia.com/wiki/Inflation_RPG_Wiki